# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(ZLjava/lang/Object;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I've looked at Firebase documentation, then searched all github issues and also all stack overflow posts but still I'm getting this error again and again. I've been stuck for hours, please have a look. It says-

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(ZLjava/lang/Object;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/app/com.masquerade.priyanshu.topcoder-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

According to other stack overflow posts when i try to change firebase core and database version, i get another bunch of errors saying incompatible version.

This is build.gradle( Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.masquerade.priyanshu.topcoder"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.0'
    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is build.gradle( Project:app ) -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

EDIT - 
Also I'm getting this warning on `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'`

The warning is -

```
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 11.6.0, 11.4.2. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 and com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please the change the following line of code from your build.gradle( Project:app ) file:

```
url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
```

with

```
url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
```

Change also this line of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
```

Change also this lines of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
```

Because `Firebase/Play Services Version 11.4.2`works with `FirebaseUI Version 3.1.0` as seen [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

Also set `multiDexEnabled` to true in default config.

Comment: On updating firebase-ui-storage I'm getting this runtime error -  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbp;

Comment: change 11.4.2 to 11.6.0 @Somebody

Comment: @Peter_Haddad nothing is 11.4.2, I've used 11.6.0 everywhere

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thanks but Somebody should change the opposite, from 11.60 to 11.4.2.

Comment: @Alex when i changed 11.6.0 to 11.4.2, I'm getting this error- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Change also this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'` with classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

Comment: I removed  - multiDexEnabled true from default config and that error gets resolved